# How to properly release BreezeJS entities for memory cleanup

Tags: breeze

I'm using BreezeJS with Angular/SQL/EF/WebAPI, based on a customized version of John Papa's HotTowel template.  All is working very well but I need assistance with memory management.

In my case my users download "missions" to the browser.  A mission is big clump of data that I crunch locally in the browser.  When the user requests a new mission, another big clump of data is downloaded.  After three missions are downloaded the browser is consuming hundreds of MegaBytes of memory as shown in windows perf monitor. This browser eventually chokes.  I believe the answer is to simply release/dispose the previous mission's entities.  What's the best way to clean up unneeded entities so they aren't consuming memory?  I've tried setDetach, nulling objects etc but memory never seems to be released.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Anyone have a thought?  The question is simply: how do I properly tell Breeze entity manager to forget about some entity and release it for garbage collection?